# Nested Flexbox with horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using a nested flexbox layout.

I would like a left nav to always be 1/3rd of the page, and the right side always be 2/3rds.

The left nav should always stay in view.

The right side (an image carousel in my case) should always take up 2/3rds and have a horizontal scrollbar on the boxes.

In the code below, it simply stretches and ignores the overflow.

```html
<div>
  Top Header (should stay in view)
</div>
<div style="display: flex">
  <div style="flex: 1 0 auto">
    LeftNav
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 2 0 auto">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; overflow-x: scroll">
      <div style="background-color: blue; min-width: 400px; height: 500px">
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: red; min-width: 400px; height: 500px">
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: green; min-width: 400px; height: 500px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @MichaelCoker fixed - the right side is 2/3rds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `flex-grow`, which simply distributes free space in the container, use `flex-basis`, which explicitly sizes your items 1/3 and 2/3.

Then, because the [**default minimum width of flex items**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276) is `min-width: auto`, meaning they cannot be smaller than the size of their content, use `min-width: 0` to override that default on the carousel.

```html
<div>
  Top Header (should stay in view)
</div>
<div style="display: flex">
  <div style="flex: 0 0 33%">LeftNav</div>
  <div style="flex: 0 0 67%; min-width: 0;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; overflow-x: scroll">
      <div style="background-color: blue; min-width: 400px; height: 500px">
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: red; min-width: 400px; height: 500px">
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: green; min-width: 400px; height: 500px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I've moved your styles to classes. Don't use inline CSS.

`flex` CSS property is shorthand for setting  `flex: [flex-grow] [flex-shrink] [flex-basis]`.

You can set fixed percentage to your `flex-basis` values and zeros to `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to avoid flex items growing and shrinking.

Also you show move `scroll` CSS to your right nav block.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
}

.left-nav {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% / 3); /* One third width */
}

.right-nav {
  flex: 0 0 calc(200% / 3); /* Two third width */
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.right-nav-container {
  display: flex;
}

.right-nav-item {
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 500px
}

.right-nav-item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.right-nav-item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.right-nav-item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Top Header (should stay in view)
</div>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="left-nav">
    LeftNav
  </div>
  <div class="right-nav">
    <div class="right-nav-container">
      <div class="right-nav-item">
      </div>
      <div class="right-nav-item">
      </div>
      <div class="right-nav-item">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```